# C simple program to get int number from the client

Tags: c

I am new to C language.
I want to create an app that get 2 int and print the sum of them.
I tried to use while to get a int number from the client, but i get an endless while loop.

```
int main()
{
    //printf("Hello world!\n");

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    printf("Insert 2 numvers \n");

    int status = scanf("%d", &x);
    while (status == 0) {
        printf("Error occured. Enter new number: \n");
        status = scanf("%d", &x);
    }

    scanf("%d", &y);

    printf("The sum is: %d", x + y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output(I don't have option to insert another number):

```
Insert new number: 
ascsac -> input
Error occured. Enter new number:
Error occured. Enter new number:
Error occured. Enter new number:
Error occured. Enter new number:
Error occured. Enter new number:
Error occured. Enter new number:
Error occured. Enter new number:
Error occured. Enter new number:
Error occured. Enter new number:
(Endless loop).
```

Comment: Duplicate of various questions where `scanf` doesn't read the newline and skips user input. Interestingly I can't find the question I'm thinking about.

Comment: Code should  also check the return value of `scanf("%d", &y)`.

Answer (score 3):

As said already , `scanf` on failure will leave the input in the `stdin` and next `scanf` in loop will read that and again fail , leading to infinite loop .

One old solution could be used -

```
 int c;
 int status = scanf("%d", &x);
 while (status == 0) {
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n');               //clear stdin before next scanf
    if(c==EOF) break;
    printf("Error occured. Enter new number: \n");
    status = scanf("%d", &x);
}
```

Comment: If `c == EOF`, no need to `printf(... scanf(...`.

Comment: @chux Yeah good point but a bit confused . Will this  do that -`if((c=getchar())==EOF)  break;` after loop ?

Comment: Code may need something like `while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'); if(c==EOF) break;`   Testing for `EOF` often messes up elegant code flow.  IAC, `scanf("%d", &y)` has the same problem as `scanf("%d", &x)`

Comment: @chux Ohh , yes as loop terminated either `c` has `EOF` or  `\n`. No need to read again in that  .

Answer (score 2):

If [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can't read and parse the input according to the format, it will leave the input in the buffer, so next iteration of the loop you try to read the exact same input as the last time.

A simple solution to this is to read a line using e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then use `sscanf` to attempt to extract the number.

Answer (score 1):

Read a line into a buffer and then test for  2 `int`.  Variation on [@Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33368765/2410359)

```
int main(void) {
  int x, y;
  const char *prompt = "Insert 2 numvers\n";

  char buffer[100];
  do {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
      return -1;
    }
    prompt = "Error occurred. Enter new number: \n";
  } while (sscanf(buffer, "%d%d", &x, &y) != 2);

  printf("The sum is: %d", x + y);
  return 0;
}
```

Code like `scanf("%d", &y);` is a potential problem as the return value was not checked, so code does not know that `y` contains valid data.